# How to create the controller for http://localhost in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using codeigniter and was hondering how to create the home page controlller, the controller for http://localhost.  As of now i can access all controllers that are http://localhost/{controller}, but not just localhost.  My .htaccess is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|sandbox|scripts|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/test/$1 [L]
```

Comment: You can set the default controller in config/routes.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the default_controller to the name of the controller you want to use in routes.php